# Placing background on a Bootstrap site

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to place a background image on this bootstrap site: http://rsatestamls.kaliocommerce.com/

But what happens, is that the background is behind everything. What I mean by that, is that there's some content I want to be -over- the background, but instead the background is everywhere. I'd just like for it to be on the sides and behind everything, not on top of everything.

This is what it looks like if I try using it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v3n5.jpg

This is why I'm using Bootstrap...I'm not great at design by any means. More of a Developer than a Designer.

So anyways, any ideas on how I can accomplish this? I'm looking for a similar affect to this background: gardeners.com

Just because I don't want to have a ton of whitespace.

What I've tried to do is add:

```
 background:url("/images/art/AMLRWDBackground.jpg");
```

To the CSS, but that looks terrible. Any ideas? I'm not even sure where to start.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this would be to have all of your content in one frame with a css value of:

```
#frame {

  background-color: #fff;

}
```

Once you have done this add the background to the body and it will work how you intend it to.